# Change image when is clicked on it, and then change it back

Tags: javascript

I'm having problem, I can't figure out how to change image back when it's not clicked on it..
 When user click on image, it shows the image that is supposed to. But, I want to change the image back after click... How can be this done? Now, when you click on image, it changes, but stays on the clicked image and changes to default one only if your mouse is not on that image..

My code..

```
<img src="pictures/fbutt.jpg" width="640" height="360"
onmouseover="this.src='pictures/fbuttho.jpg'"
onmouseout="this.src='pictures/fbutt.jpg'" onclick="this.src='pictures/fbuttac.jpg'"/>
```

Comment: You can try jQuery onmouseup and onmousedown..

Comment: @DipenDedania -  Any example please? I'm new to javascript and jQuery.

Comment: @DipenDedania JQuery doesn't reinvent the wheel. It does do the same for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example your HTML is something like this..

```
<img id="pic" src="pictures/fbutt.jpg" width="640" height="360"/>
```

Assign an id to it and bind jQuery mouseup and mousedown events on that.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pic")
      .mouseup(function() {
          $( this ).attr('src','pictures/fbuttac.jpg' );
      })
      .mousedown(function() {
          $( this ).attr('src','pictures/fbutt.jpg' );
      });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where am I supposed to write that jQuery code?I'm sorry for this dumb question but i've never done something with jquery.. i tried to put it in <script></script> tag but does not work..

Comment: I did but it does nothing.. i have included jquery in my html.. it's freak because now I tried it in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fodxvssn/1/ and it works perfectly but on my page it does not..

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this little demo using jquery:
https://jsfiddle.net/fodxvssn/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#img").mouseup(function() 
    {
        $(this).attr("src", "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=ea71a5211a91");
    });

    $("#img").mousedown(function()
    {
        $(this).attr("src", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<img id="testImage" src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/964776/images/o-CATS-KILL-BILLIONS-facebook.jpg" alt="..." width="300" height="300" />

<script>
  var imageEl = document.getElementById('testImage');
  var newImg = 'http://www.mycatspace.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/adopting-a-cat.jpg';
  var defaultImg = imageEl.src;

  imageEl.onmousedown = function() {
    this.src = newImg;
  }

  imageEl.onmouseup = function() {
    this.src = defaultImg;
  }
</script>
```